# Frontend Overflow of Semantic UI React Segment

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

In the following code, item.content often can be a tad bit too long, since I'm building out a chat interface. I've been able to make sure that the width of the segment stays within a certain limit, but how can I make sure that the text kind of wraps around? and that the height of the segment adjusts? I'm also attaching a screenshot of what it currently looks like. [image]

```
<Segment style={{maxWidth:"300px"}} inverted>
                                        <Grid.Column>
                                        {item.content}
                                                </Grid.Column>
                        </Segment>
```

Comment: look at the difference between these two divs. https://codepen.io/yael-screenovate/pen/RwrORdX and let me know it this solved your problom

Comment: Yes - this did. Thank you!